# How do I split up an array in bits in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a game which reads from an array to find out what to put where.

An example:

```
     [1,1,2,
      2,3,1,
      3,3,1]
```

How do I make it so that the last row comes first and then the second row after and so on. 
What I want:

```
    [3,3,1,
     2,3,1,
     1,1,2]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Without knowing that if it's difficult to answer your question.   - for example, the easiest solution based off what you've shared is simply define your array in the order you want.   So please update/edit the question and explain how your array get's populated, and what is in the array, and what you do with the array.     If you made a multi-dimensional array where each row is it's own array, you could then reverse it.  `var arr:Array = [[1,1,2],[2,3,1],[3,3,1]];  arr.reverse();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
// Written in JavaScript, but should work as is in AS3
var list = [1,1,2,
            2,3,1,
            3,3,1];

var rowLength = 3;
var rowCount = list.length / rowLength;

var rows = [];

for (i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
{
    var offset = i * rowLength;
    rows.push(list.slice(offset, offset + rowLength));
}

rows.reverse();

var result = [];

for (var j in rows)
{
    result = result.concat(rows[j]);
}

console.log(result); // result = [3,3,1,
                     //           2,3,1,
                     //           1,1,2];
```